# Is it possible to tile two planes, which have some line segments identified, in ways which can't be replicated on just one?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, tessellations

Suppose you have two Euclidean planes, and there is some set of pairs of points (themselves pairs of coordinates) such that for each such pair ((ax,ay),(bx,by)), the line segment connecting the point (ax,ay) to (bx,by) on plane 1 is identified with the line segment connecting those points on plane 2.

Then if that shared line segment is the edge of some tile (closed polygon) on one plane, and of another tile on the other plane, those tiles are said to be adjacent, just as two tiles sharing an edge on the same plane are adjacent. Further, we shall require that every such shared line segment is an edge of some tile.

Say then that the pair of planes together with the set of all tiles and all pairs of identified edges is a "2-planar tiling" if: 1. every edge is shared by exactly two tiles; 2. no two tiles on the same plane ever overlap; and 3. any tile on either plane can be reached from any other tile on either plane by some sequence of steps between adjacent tiles.

My question is: is there a 2-planar tiling, by this definition, which is topologically distinct from any possible tiling on just one plane? That is, having some subset of tiles which cannot occur on a single plane with the same pattern of adjacencies? If there is, what is the "most regular" such tiling?

Comment: I wonder if I understand your question correctly. You say nothing of every point being covered in at least one of the planes... therefore there are many "tilings" that are not very interesting. Or am I missing something? Also, are there no restrictions on the set of indentifoed edges? (So we could look at just at 2 such edges as a start?)

Comment: Indeed, not every point needs to be covered in at least one of the planes. The important thing is that the three requirements I laid out be followed. And indeed there are lots of "boring" such tilings, like the one you get if you put half of a square tiling into one plane, the other half in the other, and merge the line where they were cut. And there is no restriction on the set of identified edges either.

Comment: The other type of 'boring' (but slightly less) tiling is this: consider the plane with some holes cut from it, covered with tiles everywhere except the holes. Take two of these andIdentify the borders of the holes ... this works right? (The holes need to be tge same in the two planes but the actual tilings need not). We can also make a sphere: take two copies of any polygon and identify the corresponding edges.

Comment: I somehow entirely failed to consider that one could make a dihedron that way! And I also never considered the holes method, which would produce simple infinite sponge polyhedra. That pretty much answers my question, I guess! I do wonder though, what would you consider "interesting"? And I wonder if it IS possible to cover the union of the two planes in an interesting way...

Comment: I guess interesting to me would be where the tiling actually comes into play; so far all three types of examples don't require a tiling. You can change the question to "how can we cut and stitch two planes together?" If we partition two planes the same way into sets $X$ and $Y$, we make a new shape by taking $X_1$ and $Y_2$ (that's your example), or $X_1$ and $X_2$ (or $Y_1$ and $Y_2$), which are my examples. (There is some conditions necessary to avoid anything we don't want. This is implicitly what the tiling does in the original question; it limits the partitions to be "nice").

Comment: Basically what I'm realizing now is that I asked a really stupid question. I should have abstracted away from "tilings" and realized that what I was doing was just a topological modification of a plane.